# Nvidia driver issue

Tags: nvidia, graphics, acer

I have a laptop with an nVidia 9300m GS 512mb graphics chip. When I install the nvidia drivers, either of the options (current or post release), it repeats my screen 6 times on the same screen, with grey bars separating them horizontally and a thicker black line vertically. How do I fix this?

Update:

it appears to believe it is a "separate X screen" with a resolution of 640x480 (won't let me set it higher, should be 1366x768) It recognises the chip and the laptop models exactly so should work.

Comment: it appears to believe it is a "separate X screen" with a resolution of 640x480 (won't let me set it higher, should be 1366x768)
It recognises the chip and the laptop models exactly so should work.

Comment: You can edit your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the xorg conf file. See if it works.

`sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup`

Reboot the system.

If above doesn't work, probably your graphics card is not supported any more.

Use x-updates ppa to get updated drivers.

Type in terminal,

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates      
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Or you can also use proprietary nvidia drivers from [here(64bit)](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-295.59-driver.html) . However your product isn't listed here. It is `9300m GS` & `9300m G`